# R - Warning: unable to access index for repository

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu

Here is my OS details:

```
$ uname -a
Linux starbuck 3.2.0-92-generic #131-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 20 16:16:02 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Here is my R version:

```
$ R --version
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) -- "Fire Safety"
```

Here is my `.Rprofile`:

```
options("repos" = c(CRAN = "https://cran.r-project.org"))
```

Now when I open R and try to list the available packages I get:

```
 > available.packages()
 Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib
 Package Version Priority Depends Imports LinkingTo Suggests Enhances
 License License_is_FOSS License_restricts_use OS_type Archs MD5sum
 NeedsCompilation File Repository
```

Comment: Are you sure your computer has internet connectivity? Did you try other CRAN mirrors (`chooseCRANmirror()`)?

Comment: What is the output of `capabilities("libcurl")`?

Comment: Yes, I have an active internet connection. If I try another mirror I get the same error (`Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.revolutionanalytics.com/src/contrib`)

Comment: `capabilities("libcurl")` is returning `FALSE`. I'm assuming that is bad?

Comment: Yes, it is. You cannot access https. This [recent thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2015-November/433682.html) might help you to solve the problem.

Comment: I install R off of https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/. How can I get libcurl support?

Comment: This [recent thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2015-November/433682.html) might help you to solve the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94274/discussion-between-mikeycgto-and-pascal).